# PairedBarChart with negative values

Tags: plotting, charts

I want to plot negative values using `PairedBarChart` in V9.
However, with this code

```
PairedBarChart[{0.0000254914, -0.0000222568, 0.0756163,}, 
 {0.00043002, 0.0709322, 0.0681315}, PlotRange -> {{-0.002, 20}, All}]
```

I get:

> PairedBarChart::ldata: "{0.0000254914,-0.0000222568,0.0756163} is not a valid dataset or list of datasets.

How can I plot negative values with `PairedBarChart` in V9?

Many thanks in advance
Sofia

Answer (score 5):

[PairedBarChart >> Possible Issues](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PairedBarChart.html):

> *PairedBarChart* does not accept negative values:

A work-around is to combine two `BarChart`s using `Row`:

```
SeedRandom[0]
data = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {2, 10}];
opts = {ChartStyle -> 63, BarOrigin -> Left, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, ImageSize -> 500};

Panel[Row[BarChart[#, opts] & /@ data, Spacer[10]]]
```

[image]

Of course, we lose the convenience of some `PairedBarChart` options such as `ChartLabels`. To add labels we can use `Epilog` in the first chart and use appropriate image padding to get both charts with the same size:

```
labels = CharacterRange["A", "Z"][[;; 10]];
epilog = Inset[Style[#, "Panel", 16, Bold], #2] & @@@ 
               Transpose[{labels, Thread[{1.2 Max[data[[1]]], Range[10]}]}];

Panel[Row[{BarChart[data[[1]], opts, Epilog -> epilog, 
    ImagePadding -> {{0, 40}, {20, 0}}, 
    ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle"], 
   BarChart[data[[2]], ImagePadding -> {{0, 40}, {20, 0}}, opts, 
    ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle"]}, Spacer[5]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @kguler, `PairedBarChart` does not accept negative values. However, you can get the desired output by adding a constant offset to your data list so they are all non-negative and change the tick labels by `Ticks->{..}` like this:

```
data1 = {1, -2, 3}; data2 = {-2, 1, -3};

min = Min[data1, data2];
max = Max[data1, data2];

offset = -min + 1;

PairedBarChart[data1 + offset, data2 + offset, 
 Ticks -> {Table[{i, i - offset}, {i, 0, max + offset}]}]
```

[image: output]

This code may not be very robust and you'll have to adjust the offset/ticks as appropriate.